# delete line if string is matched and the next line contains another string

Tags: awk, sed, grep

got an annoying text manipulation problem, i need to delete a line in a file if it contains a string but only if the next line also contains another string. for example, i have these lines:

```
john paul
george
john paul
12
john paul
```

i want to delete any line containing 'john paul' if it is immediately followed by a line that contains 'george', so it would return:

```
george
john paul
12
john paul
```

not sure how to grep or sed this. if anyone could lend a hand that'd be great!

Comment: grep is for finding a regexp on one 1 line. sed is for replacing a regexp on 1 line. For anything else, awk is the correct tool to use.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/john paul/{$!N;/\n.*george/!P;D}' file
```

If the line contains `john paul` read the next line and if it contains `george` don't print the first line.

N.B. If the line containing `george` contains `john paul` it will be checked also.

Comment: Hi, I hadn't seen this nice and short answer at the moment when I posted my **sed** solution below... Can you please explain the `$!N`? And the `D` command will load a new line at the same time when it deletes the first line of the pattern space (am I right here?), isn't it a potential issue?

Comment: @jaybee `$!N` means don't try to get the next line when you are at the end-of-file. The `D` deletes upto the first newline in the pattern space and if the pattern space is empty invokes the normal sed cycle which gets the next line etc. If the pattern space is not empty, the sed script is invoked skipping the normal process of getting the next line and stripping the newline.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR > 1 && !(/george/ && p ~ /john paul/) { print p } { p = $0 } END { print }' file
```

Output:

```
george
john paul
12
john paul
```

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
cat file
john paul
george
john paul
12
john paul
hans
george
```

```
awk 'f~/john paul/ && /george/ {f=$0;next} NR>1 {print f} {f=$0} END {print}' file
george
john paul
12
john paul
hans
george
```

This will only delete name above `george` if it is `john paul`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one version more general:
if the lines matches a string and previous line was exactly "john paul" then do nothing,  otherwise, print the previous line. (change the `^[a-zA-Z]$` part to `george` if you only want `george` to be detected.

```
awk '!(/^[a-zA-W]+$/ && previous ~/^john paul$/){print previous}{previous=$0}END{print}'
```

In your example:

```
$> echo 'john paul
george
john paul
12
john paul' |awk '!(/^[a-zA-W]+$/ && previous ~/^john paul$/){print previous}{previous=$0}END{print}'

george
john paul
12
john paul
```

if there is some numbers in the line, it prints the previous, otherwise it doesn't:

```
$> echo 'john paul
george 234
john paul
auie
john paul' |awk '!(/^[a-zA-W]+$/ && previous ~/^john paul$/){print previous}{previous=$0}END{print}'

john paul
george 234
auie
john paul
```

Comment: This is just the same as the solution from konsolebox, except you are missing the `NR>1 &&` in the start to prevent one blank line.

Answer (score 1):

The **sed** solution is short: two commands and lots of comments ;)

```
/john paul/ {
        # read the next line and append to pattern space
        N   
        # and then if we find "george" in that next line,
        # only retain the last line in the pattern space
        s/.*\n\(.*george\)/\1/
        # and finally print the pattern space,
        # as we don't use the -n option
}
```

You put the above in some `sedscript` file and then run:

```
sed -f sedscript your_input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw some Perl into the mix:

```
perl -ne 'print $p unless /george/ && $p =~ /john paul/; $p = $_ }{ print $p' file
```

Print the previous line, unless the current line matches `/george/` and the previous line `$p` matched `/john paul/`. Set `$p` to the value of the previous line. `}{` effectively creates an `END` block, so the last line is also printed after the file has been read.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change the \r\n to \n or to \r, other than that this should work:

```
<?php
$string = "john paul
george
john paul
12
john paul";

$string = preg_replace("#john paul\r\n(george)#i",'$1',$string);

echo $string;
?>
```

You could also read a file into the variable and then after overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ gawk -vRS='^$' '{gsub(/john paul\ngeorge/,"george")}1' file
george
john paul
12
john paul
```

or if there's more on each line than your sample input shows just change the RE to suit and use gensub():

```
$ gawk -vRS='^$' '{$0 = gensub(/[^\n]*john paul[^\n]*\n([^\n]*george[^\n]*)/,"\\1","")}1' file
george
john paul
12
john paul
```