# Search file of directories and find file names, save to new file - bash

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to find the paths for some `fastq.gz` files in a mess of a system.

I have some folder paths in a file called `temp` (subset):

```
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG167/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG178/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG213/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG230/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG234/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG250/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG251/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG257/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG263/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG265/temp/
```

Let's assume 2 `fastq.gz` files are found in each directory in `temp` except for `/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG265/temp/`.

I want to find the `fastq.gz` files and print them (if found) next to the directory I'm searching in.

Ideal output:

```
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG167/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG167/NG167_S19_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG178/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG178/NG178_S1_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG178/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG178/NG178_S1_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG213/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG213/NG213_S20_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG213/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG213/NG213_S20_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG230/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG230/NG230_S23_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG230/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG230/NG230_S23_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG234/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG234/NG234_S18_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG234/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG234/NG234_S18_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG250/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG250/NG250_S2_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG250/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG250/NG250_S2_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG251/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG251/NG251_S3_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG251/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG251/NG251_S3_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG257/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG257/NG257_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG257/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG257/NG257_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG263/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG263/NG263_S22_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG263/    found   /temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG263/NG263_S22_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG265/temp/   not_found
```

I'm part the way there:

```
wc -l temp
while read -r line; do cd $line; echo ${line} >> ~/tmp; find `pwd -P` -name "*fastq.gz" >> ~/tmp; done < temp
cd ~
less tmp
```

Current output:

```
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG167/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG167/NG167_S19_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG167/NG167_S19_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG178/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG178/NG178_S1_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG178/NG178_S1_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG213/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG213/NG213_S20_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG213/NG213_S20_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG230/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG230/NG230_S23_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG230/NG230_S23_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG234/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG234/NG234_S18_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG234/NG234_S18_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG250/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG250/NG250_S2_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG250/NG250_S2_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG251/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG251/NG251_S3_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG251/NG251_S3_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG257/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG257/NG257_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG257/NG257_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG263/
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG263/NG263_S22_R1_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG263/NG263_S22_R2_001.fastq.gz
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG265/temp/
```

My code places the directory searched for first, then any matching files on subsequent lines. I'm not sure how to get the output I desire...

Any help, gratefully received!
Thanks,

Comment: Because I want to match that pattern with another pattern later down the line...

Comment: Do you care about the empty directories? [makes it much easier :-)]

Comment: I care about knowing which paths are empty, as they'll be a few cases and I'll need to investigate a bit further! Sorry to be a pain! I suppose given I have the directories in temp, I can grep out the directories which do have a match to show me the ones that don't...

Comment: Consider using [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), or write your [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) script. Take a few days to learn one of theml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not your original script but this version does not run `cd` and `find` on each line in this case each directory but the whole directory tree/structure just once and the parsing is done inside the `while read` loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t to_search < temp.txt

while IFS= read -rd '' files; do
  if [[ $files == *.fastq.gz ]]; then
    printf '%s found %s\n' "${files%/*}/" "$files"
  else
    printf '%s not_found!\n' "$files" >&2
  fi
done < <(find "${to_search[@]%/*.fastq.gz*}" -print0) | column -t
```

---

This is how I would rewrite your script. Using cd in a subshell

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r line; do
  if [[ -d "$line" ]]; then
    (
      cd "$line" || exit
      varname=$(find "$(pwd -P)" -name '*fastq.gz')
      if [[ -n $varname ]]; then
        printf '%s found %s\n' "$line" "$line${varname#*./}"
      else
        printf '%s not_found!\n' "$line"
      fi
    )
  fi
done < temp.txt | column -t
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm trying to learn off your (expert) code, instead of my pathetic attempt! I really like the second option (since the output has both found and not found in a nice output), although is it possible (please) to have multiple fastq.gz file matches on subsequent lines but with the file path searched and 'found' appended, as with the first match? So it looks like my 'desired' output. I want one row per directory searched and full path to fastq.gz file if possible...

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking. Do you have more fastq.gz files in on directory?

Answer (score 0):

Given a line -

```
/temp/CC49/DATA/Gh7d/NYSTAG_TSO_Mar16/NG263/NG263_S22_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

you can get what you want for the found lines quite easily with sed - just feed the lines to it.

```
 ... | sed -e 's#^\(.*/\)\([^/]*\)$#\1    found   \1\2#'
```

However, that doesn't eliminate the line before.

To do that you either use something like awk (and do a simple state machine), or do something like this in sed (general idea here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25203093).

```
... | sed -e '#/$#{$!N;#\n.*gz$#!P;D}'
```

(although I think I have a typo as it is not working for me on osx).

So then you'd be left with the .gz lines already converted, and the lines ending in / where you can also use sed to then append the "not found".

```
... | sed -e 's#/$#/    not found#'
```